# Python Math Library Independent of C Math Library and Platform Independent?

Tags: python

Does the built-in Python math library basically use C's math library or does Python have a C-independent math library? Also, is the Python math library platform independent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at the bottom of [the page it says](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html):

> **Note:** The `math` module consists mostly of thin wrappers around the platform C `math` library functions. Behavior in exceptional cases is loosely specified by the C standards, and Python inherits much of its `math`-function error-reporting behavior from the platform C implementation. As a result, the specific exceptions raised in error cases (and even whether some arguments are considered to be exceptional at all) are not defined in any useful cross-platform or cross-release way. For example, whether `math.log(0)` returns `-Inf` or raises `ValueError` or `OverflowError` isn’t defined, and in cases where `math.log(0)` raises `OverflowError`, `math.log(0L)` may raise `ValueError` instead.
>
> All functions return a quiet NaN if at least one of the args is `NaN`. Signaling `NaN`s raise an exception. The exception type still depends on the platform and libm implementation. It’s usually `ValueError` for `EDOM` and `OverflowError` for `errno ERANGE`.
>
> *Changed in version 2.6*: In earlier versions of Python the outcome of an operation with `NaN` as input depended on platform and `libm` implementation.

Comment: Does this mean that Python uses the current platform's implementation of math.h?

Comment: suppose so, here is relevant code I believe http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Include/pymath.h

Comment: @paradius, how ELSE could you _possibly_ interpret "thin wrappers around the platform C math library" differently than "uses the current platform's implementation"...?

Answer (score 2):

Python uses the C library it is linked against. On Windows, there is no 'platform C library'.. and indeed there are multiple versions of MicrosoftCRunTimeLibrarys (MSCRTs) around on any version.